# how do i make eye icon visible when accordion open

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Hello dear stackoverflow users.
I have an accordion. When this accordion is open, I want to make the invisible eye icon next to it visible. But which accordion is clicked, only its eye icon will open. Please help me :)

My code :

```js
var collapsebtn = document.querySelectorAll('.data-toggle');
var eyes = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');

for (i = 0; i < collapsebtn.length; i++) {
  collapsebtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     eyes[i].classList.remove('d-none');
  })
}
```

```html
 <a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-4 border-bottom fw-bold mb-2 pb-4">
    <div class="col-6">PPGI Stell</div>
    <div class="col-3">10.000</div>
    <div class="col-3">Tons <span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="index1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
<a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-5 border-bottom fw-bold mb-5 pb-4">
    <div class="col-6">Steel Cable </div>
    <div class="col-3">1400</div>
    <div class="col-3">Meters<span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="index2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
<a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">

  <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-5 border-bottom fw-bold mb-5 pb-4">
    <div class="col-6">HDPE Molding Plastic</div>
    <div class="col-3">1400</div>
    <div class="col-3">Tons<span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
</div>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="index3">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate througth forEach callback, and get the index from argument and make reference to the eye via the index, the function is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

```js
let collapsebtn = document.querySelectorAll('.data-toggle');
let eyes = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');

//console.log(eyes);
//console.log(collapsebtn);


collapsebtn.forEach(function(element, index){

  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    eyes[index].classList.remove('d-none');
  });


});
```

```html
<a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                    <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-4 border-bottom fw-bold mb-2 pb-4">
                                        <div class="col-6">PPGI Stell</div>
                                        <div class="col-3">10.000</div>
                                        <div class="col-3">Tons <span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="index1">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                    <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-5 border-bottom fw-bold mb-5 pb-4">
                                        <div class="col-6">Steel Cable </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">1400</div>
                                        <div class="col-3">Meters<span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="index2">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="data-toggle" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#index3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">

                                    <div class="request-table row flex-wrap mt-5 border-bottom fw-bold mb-5 pb-4">
                                        <div class="col-6">HDPE Molding Plastic</div>
                                        <div class="col-3">1400</div>
                                        <div class="col-3">Tons<span class="d-none eye"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="index3">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll check the link now. I'm grateful :)